# replacing componentDidUpdate with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I'm replacing lifecycle methods in class based component into `useEffect`hooks since I'm into functional component. I'm not sure I'm using useEffect properly..

we can't point previous state or props in `useEffect`, how can I deal with these with `useEffect`?

Let's say we have props named src, and I want to check if this `src` has changed, If not, there would be some logic for it.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { src } = this.props; 

if(prevProps.src !== src) {
   this.cleanUp(); 
   this.init(); 
} else{
   // todo something 
}
}
```

how can I deal with this using `useEffect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
function App(props) {
  const { src } = props;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    init();
    return () => cleanup();
  }, [src]);
```

If cleanup and init aren't static functions and need to access local state or props then I need to see more code and probably have to use useCallback on init and cleanup so you can make them dependencies of the effect to avoid [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) or infinite renders.

Here is an example of external init function using useCallback:

```js
//message channel has getAll, sendMessage and addListener
//  this is just an example and added to demonstrate hooks
const messageChannel = (() => {
  //function creating id to give each message unique id
  const id = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
  let listeners = [];
  const data = {};
  const addListener = (channel, callback) => {
    listeners.push({ channel, callback });
    //return a function that when called will remove
    //  listener
    return () =>
      (listeners = listeners.filter(
        ({ callback: fn }) => callback !== fn
      ));
  };
  const dispatch = (channel, newData) =>
    listeners
      .filter(({ channel: c }) => c === channel)
      .forEach(({ callback }) => callback(newData));
  const sendMessage = (channel, message) => {
    if (!data[channel]) {
      data[channel] = [];
    }
    const newMessage = { id: id(), message };
    data[channel] = [newMessage, ...data[channel]];
    dispatch(channel, newMessage);
  };
  const getAll = (channel) => data[channel] || [];
  return {
    addListener,
    sendMessage,
    getAll,
  };
})(); //IIFE creating message channel

function Messages({ channel }) {
  //local messages state that holds messages for this channel
  const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([]);
  //using useCallback so init only changes when channel changes
  const init = React.useCallback(
    //set local messages to all messages of this channel
    () => setMessages(messageChannel.getAll(channel)),
    [channel]//re create init when channel changes
  );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //call init to set all messages of current channel
    init();
    //add listener for new messages on current channel
    //  addListener returns a function that will remove
    //  the listener when called
    const cleanup = messageChannel.addListener(
      channel,
      //handler for new messages will add new message
      //  to local list of messages
      (newMessage) =>
        //do not mutate state, create a new messages array
        setMessages((messages) => [newMessage, ...messages])
    );
    //return the cleanup function, when channel changes
    //  react will call it and it will remove listener
    //  for previous channel
    return cleanup;
  }, [channel, init]);
  //both channel and init are a dependency but init
  //  only changes when channel changes, it will still
  //  function when removing init from the dependencies
  //  but the linter will complain
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>channel: {channel}</h3>
      <ul>
        {messages.map(({ message, id }) => (
          <li key={id}>{message}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [channel, setChannel] = React.useState('A');
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
  const sendMessage = () =>
    messageChannel.sendMessage(channel, message);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Channel
          <select
            onChange={(e) => setChannel(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={sendMessage}>send message</button>
      </div>
      <Messages channel={channel} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Think of `useEffect` has a "hook" in this case, that relies on something to trigger it when there's a change.

If you give `useEffect` nothing, it will just be triggered once on load. This is the equivalent to `componentDidMount`.

If you give it multiple object or elements to follow it will trigger based on the changes of those elements.

**TL;DR:**

```js
const App = props => {
   useEffect(() => {
      // your code
   }, [props.yourPropertyToWatch]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on [@hmr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62655179/11317072)'s feedback, it would be ideal to add the clean up as well, which is the equivalent of `componentWillUnmount`.

```js
const App = props => {
   useEffect(() => {
      // your code

      // once done with the component
      return () => {
         // your unmount code
      }
   }, [props.yourPropertyToWatch]);
}
```

Comment: There is no cleanup

Comment: It is not unmount, the cleanup runs whenever `props.yourPropertyToWatch ` changes (see example in my answer).

Comment: Wait, I thought it was only run on unmount though, that's what I understood from the docs, but am I interpreting that incorrectly? "When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts" (React Hook - Example Using Hooks 1 - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

Comment: Yes, it's run every time a dependency changes and on unmount. The docs don't have a dependent effect example with cleanup so I added one to my answer. If I change channel in my example and would not clean up, the listener would still be listening to the previous channel and cause unexpected results as well as a memory leak.

Comment: Nice! I like the added article you posted. This is definitely worth reading. Going to experiment with this myself a little later today. Thanks for giving some more context on it, much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to show a stale closure is take my example in the anser and in `const init = React.useCallback(` remove the `channel` dependency. Now when you switch channels it'll only show messages for channel A since init is never re created and closes over `channel` when it was A. This is why linters complain when they detect missing dependencies. You can play with the code in my answer by clicking the "copy snippet to answer" button